# Get an array element by position defined in same document as different field in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Is there any easy way to get an array element by its position. Where position is defined in same document as different field.

Example Document:

```
{
    _id:"123",
    "elementPosition": 3,
    "users": [
              {
                "username": "abcd"
              },
              {
                "username": "qweqw"
              },
              {
                "username": "fdsfsd"
              },
              {
                "username": "dsfvd"
              }
    ]

}
```

Further if there is some easy way then also want to do below operation in efficient way:

1. Updaate Document where users.elementPosition.username = "abcd" and update "users.elementPosition.username" = "wxyz"

***elementPosition from same document.

I have tried so many ways. One of them was get get elementPosition and then check whether documents match using that elementPosition or not. But that is dirty and lengthy.

Tried to use elementPosition as variable in single query  `"user."+elementPosition+".username"` but didn't work.

Also tried different way of aggregate queries but not getting good results. 
projecting `$elementPosition` to next stage and use that to retrieve specific position document but didn't get what I want.

Comment: any reason for down vote the question?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [$arrayElemAt Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
    db.collection.aggregate(
    {$match : {_id: "123"} },
    {$project : {username: {$arrayElemAt: [ "$users.username", "$elementPosition" ]}}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Useful... Final goal is to update element in array at position defined in same document.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your follow-up question where you would like to update the documents whose `username = "abcd"` to `"wxyz"` using the position defined in the same document, you can use the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** method to carry out the update efficiently. The following shows how to go about it with MongoDB 3.2 or greater:

```
var bulkUpdateOperations = [],
    counter = 0,
    setObj = {};

db.collection.find({ 
    "users.username": "abcd",
    "elementPosition": { "$exists": true }
}).forEach(function(doc) {  
    setObj["users."+ doc.elementPosition +".username"] = "wxyz";
    bulkUpdateOperations.push({
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": setObj }
        }
    });

    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOperations);
        bulkUpdateOperations = [];
    }
})

if (counter % 1000 != 0) { db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOperations); }
```

---

If using older versions of MongoDB i.e. v2.6 or 3.0 then use the **[Bulk Operations API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** which is supported in those versions:

```
var bulk = [],
    counter = 0,
    setObj = {};

db.collection.find({ 
    "users.username": "abcd",
    "elementPosition": { "$exists": true }
}).forEach(function(doc) {  
    setObj["users."+ doc.elementPosition +".username"] = "wxyz";
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ "$set": setObj });

    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (counter % 1000 != 0) { bulk.execute(); };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Not this: update the documents whose username = "abcd" to "wxyz"...
I Want this:
update the documents where  users.elementPosition.username = "abcd" and update "users.elementPosition.username" = "wxyz" 
"user.elementPosition.username" = "abcd" here elementPosition is defined in same document. 

Seems like to get matching document I can use [Atchoum's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37250463/5236174) solution and  and yours to update documents.